# How to paste HTML code from clipboard in Outlook Message and display HTML rich text

Tags: html, email, outlook

My office staff send their work updates by copying text from their web dashboard to an Outlook email. Because of this the emails are sent in all forms and sizes.

Now I have included a button next to every record which can copy the relevant info for that record in HTML code. Now I want to paste this HTML code in a new message in Outlook however, I don't want to paste the code as is, rather Outlook should paste it in HTML rich text format.

I don't have anything fancy, just want outlook to read line breaks, bold and colour which I have defined in HTML with `<BR>, <B> and font style tags.`